# Javascript: How to remove attribute required for all input inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an issue with my Javascript. I have a button which dynamically adds a div with 4 inputs each time we click on it (the button).

All these inputs are required. I can delete the div with a button that deletes the selected div. It works when the inputs are not empty.

When I want to delete a div with empty inputs, I cannot because of required attribute. I try to add the var test to delete required attribute before calling the action which deletes the div, but it doesn't work.

It seems like it is not difficult, but I am not very good in JS. Someone could explain me how to do this?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
        var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
        var test = document.getElementById('test');

        var x = 1; //initlal text box count
        $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();
            if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
                x++; //text box increment
                $(wrapper).before('<div><input type="Submit" value="Supprimer" name="bouton" class="remove_field"><table style="color:black; background-color:#eee; border-radius:10px; border:none;"><tr><td><span class="description">Prénom du chat</span><input type="text" name="nom_chat[]" id="test" required/></td><td><span class="description">Age du chat</span><input type="text" name="age_chat[]" id="test" required/></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2"><span class="description">Tolérance avec les autres animaux</span><textarea name="tolerance_chat[]" style="height:100px;" id="test" required></textarea></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2"><span class="description">Description du chat</span><textarea name="description_chat[]" style="height:100px;" id="test" required></textarea></td></tr></table></div>'); //add input box

            }
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault(); $(test).removeAttr('required');
            e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
        })
    });
```

My HTML:

```
            <button class="add_field_button">Ajouter un chat</button>
            <div class="input_fields_wrap"></div>
```

Comment: You are adding duplicate IDs... e.g. `id="test"`. That is invalid HTML and jQuery will only find the first match. You need to sort that out first (use classes instead).

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of problems:

- Duplicate IDs in the appended fields... I changed these to a dummy `class="test"` for now.
- Using string literals for templates is a maintenance nightmare. I have moved it to a dummy script block with unknown type so the browsers will ignore it, but you can access it by ID.
- Do the delete relative to the delete button pressed.
- Count the items when you go to add a new one (count children of the wrapper).

**Main problem:**
but the main problem was that you were inserting the new fields before the wrapper *and not inside it* so your delegated event handler did nothing.

Here is a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/q6w13L8f/1/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var max_fields = 2; //maximum input boxes allowed
     var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
     var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
     // var test = document.getElementById('test'); // UNUSED

     $(add_button).click(function (e) { //on add input button click
         var count = wrapper.children().length
         e.preventDefault();
         if (count < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
             $(wrapper).append($('#template').html()); //add input box
         }
     });

     $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) { //user click on remove text
         e.preventDefault();
         $(this).closest('.fields').remove();
     })
 });
```

The HTML now looks like this (note template is now editable as HTML instead a string):

```
<script id="template" type="text/template">
<div class="fields">
    <input type="Submit" value="Supprimer" name="bouton" class="remove_field">
    <table style="color:black; background-color:#eee; border-radius:10px; border:none;">
        <tr>
            <td><span class="description">Prénom du chat</span>
                <input type="text" name="nom_chat[]" class="test" required/>
            </td>
            <td><span class="description">Age du chat</span>
                <input type="text" name="age_chat[]" class="test" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><span class="description">Tolérance avec les autres animaux</span>
                <textarea name="tolerance_chat[]" style="height:100px;" class="test" required></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><span class="description">Description du chat</span>
                <textarea name="description_chat[]" style="height:100px;" class="test" required></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</script>
<button class="add_field_button">Ajouter un chat</button>
<div class="input_fields_wrap"></div>
```

**Update**

The requirement is to insert new forms at the start, in which case use `prepend` instead of `append`:

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/q6w13L8f/2/

Comment: Thank you so much. Now, I need to understand this stuff :).

Comment: The simple version is you needed to append the new forms inside the wrapper. Not use `before`. Your close handler was attached to a sibling instead of an ancestor :)

Comment: I understand the code now. But in fact, I need to add the new inputs before the oldest. That's why I used before and not append. Do you know what I mean ?

Comment: Use `prepend` instead to place them at the start. Will update answer. `before` means insert before *as a sibling* (not a child).

Comment: Mark as answer when you can :)